# Data field not properly loading dict for Request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to push this JSON into the data request, but I tink that the format is not passing in correctly. I keep getting a bad request. I know this request works when I put it in my REST client. 
Am I not formating JSON correctly forthe post request?

```
import json
import requests
import pprint


json_obj1 = """
  'dateStart': '2019-11-25T00:00:00.000Z',
  'dateEnd': '2019-11-26T23:59:59.999Z',
  'subscriptions': 
    {
      'category': {
        'name': 'Accessories',
        'childrenUuids': [],
        'uuid': 'c35cb71f-5dcd-4ae3-86b3-d642208ad7f5'
      },
      'geography': {
        'uuid': 'ad63a8ff-f636-44e1-9fe0-1d1664dfd530',
        'name': 'New York',
        'geoType': 'METRO',
        'childrenUuids': []
      }
    }

"""


s = requests.session()


s.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
infra_link = <someURL>
infra_content = s.request(
    method='POST', url=infra_link, data=json_obj1, headers=s.headers,
).text
```

RESULT:

{"timestamp":"2019-11-27T16:22:49.885+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad '
'Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Bad '
 'Request","path":"/index"}')

Comment: I added "data=json.dumps(json_string1)" but I am still gettign a bad request.

Comment: Did you check that your `json_data` is also a `string` and not a `dict`?

Comment: Take a look now -  this is what I am sending.

Comment: What I am putting in the string (json_obj1) is exactly what I pout into my REST client.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ your `json_obj1` is currently not a valid `json` string. As for what you're putting in your `REST` client, we have no idea what's been done under the hood there, your data may be sanitized in weird ways

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
infra_content = s.request(
    method='POST', url=infra_link, data=json_string1, headers=s.headers,
).text
```

To this

```
infra_content = s.request(
    method='POST', url=infra_link, data=json.dumps(json_string1), headers=s.headers,
).text
```

Added json.dump() in request data parameter.

Comment: I am still gettign a bad request

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a json string as your `data` argument, you're passing a `dict`.

Try the following:

```
infra_content = s.request(
    method='POST', url=infra_link, data=json.dumps(json_string1), headers=s.headers,
).text
```

Your variable `json_string1` is badly named, which might be confusing you. As you can see, it's not a string but a dict (and json is a specific string format, but a string format nonetheless). `json.dumps` (which stands for ***dump*** as **s**tring) is used to serialize a dict into a json string.

Comment: I am still getting a bad request - there a way I can check how "data " is going to interpret? In the documentation it says it wants a dict.

Comment: since you named your variable `json_string1` we assumed that you wanted a json string, if this is not the issue we can't help without you clarifying your question

Comment: I understand - take a look now - this is what I am doing